# Hydro Plant not allowing water flow through

Tags: cities-skylines

In my city, I have a hydro plant that is sitting across a river quite near my city. This dam holds back all of the water and there is a significant drop in water level before and after. When I say significant difference, I mean that on the up-river side the river is lapping at the edges of the river and at the down-river side, the river is totally empty.

However, my problem is that the hydro plant doesn't let any water through, and therefore is not generating any power (0MWh out). I can't for the life of me work out why this is happening, and it's bugging me because I don't want to have to buy another solar plant just yet.

The river in question runs out of a lake, joins with another river and then runs out into the sea. Although I do have water pumps on the upriver side of the dam, they are not consuming anywhere near enough water to totally drain the river.

Are there any ideas as to why I can't get my free river power?

Edit:

[image: Y U No Power]

Comment: Have you checked which way the dam is facing? Maybe show us a screenshot

Comment: Yes, this was the first thing I checked. The dam is definitely oriented the correct way. Love to show a screenshot but I'm at work.

Comment: Thanks for the pic. Can you check the water map if the river is still flowing? Maybe it's placed to close to the source it does no longer move. Also try to connect it to the power network and connect a road. Wait for about 5 minutes(real time) with x3 speed. That's waht i found so far.

Comment: Connected to the power, no movement on the river however. Why would placing it too close to the source cause an issue.

Comment: Might be because your dam is too high.

Comment: Read the [3 first results](https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-ssjVZ7DB9LBgATmx4DgCg&gws_rd=ssl#q=cities+skylines+hydro+dam+not+operating), good hints on why a dam won't work. If anything fix this, please write up a answer, I also plan on getting a dam eventually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since we figured it out in the comments here the answer:

> Your dam is placed to close to the water source so your river has
>   stopped flowing.

Apparently the the system works this way: There is a source point which generates water until it reaches a certain level. If that level is reached it stops producing water.
So when you build your dam your water level has risen above that threshold and there is no more water being produced, hence you created a new lake. Congratulations on that. ;)

Move your dam further along the river to fix the issue.

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me.  Hopefully that'll get fixed.